# Returning data from rest web service with NO parameters in uri

Tags: java, rest, servlets, return, inputstream

Having an issue returning a String from a rest web service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/Filters", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
string CreateFilter(Filter InputFilter);
```

As you can see the URL does not have any parameters, all the data is passed via stream to the URL. The string returned is based on the data sent to the URL.

When I use a .net testing application the response is correct (based on the input).

When I use a Java servlet the service returns a 400 error when GetInputStream() for the HttpURLRequest is called.

It appears the Java servlet makes a second call to the URL and expects a response (that doesn't exist as it is based on the input). I tested this by changing the return to a constant (thus not based on input). When I do this my GetInputStream() method works.

servlet Code:

```
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
out.write(jsonValue.getBytes());
out.close();

String response = "";


BufferedReader readResponse = 
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

response = readResponse.readLine();


return response;
```

Note: Other methods use this same code for a URL with parameters in it, and return the correct data (adding evidence that the servlet is making a second call to the URL in my problem method.) Also out.close() is NOT the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This ended up being a problem in the Json that the Servlet was sending. When the the web service tried to use one specific piece of the data it would throw and error and not produce the required return string.

```
[{"Key":"1","Value":"one"},{"Key":"2","Value":"two"},{"Key":"3","Value":"three"}]
```

C# representation ^^

```
{"3":"three","2":"two","1":"one"}
```

Java representation ^^

Dictionary vs HashMap ><